# Простейшая программа на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте. 
Помогите с написанием программы на "псевдоассемблере".

Условие:

```
x=2; y=0;
while(x<1024)
{
x=x*x;
y+=x;
}
return y;
```

x хранится в 100-й ячейке, а y - в 101-й.

Вот первые команды:

```
КОП Ах, #100 ;(копируем из 100-й ячейки в Ах)
КОП Вх, #101 ;(копируем из 101-й ячейки в Вх)
КОП Сх, Ах
УМН Сх, Ах ; умножаем Сх на Ах
УМН Сх, Сх
УМН Сх, Сх
УМН Сх, Сх
УМН Сх, Сх
УМН Сх, Сх
УМН Сх, Сх
УМН Сх, Сх
УМН Сх, Сх
```

И дальше не понимаю, что нужно написать.
Еще возможно использовать следующие мнемокоды:

```
NOT Ах ; отрицание
ИНК Ах ; +1
ЛДС и ПДС - циклические сдвиги
СДЛ и СДП - нециклические сдвиги
СТОП - безусловный переход
СРВ Ах, Вх - сравнение
```

Comment: А где описание других мнемокодов? Условные переходы у вашего ассеблера есть?

Comment: @eicto, добавил все возможные мнемокоды в вопрос. Условных переходов, по-видимому, нет.

Comment: @compl, если переходы только безусловные, то всё плохо, без условных переходов `while` не сделать. Может, ваш ассемблер поддерживает какие-нибудь хитрые режимы адресации? Относительную, например. Тогда можно делать безусловный переход на `n` байт вперёд ил назад, причём `n` вычисляется таким образом, чтобы при `x < 1024` получался адрес начала цикла, а при `x >= 1024` - следующая за переходом команда.

Comment: Если есть сравнение, то должен быть условный переход. Сравнение без условного перехода - бессмыслица.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ребята. В начале кода же написано x=2; а потом while(x<1024). Так что можно обойтись без условного перехода, просто 10 раз продублировав x=x`*`x; и y+=x; (так как 2^10 = 1024). То есть развернуть цикл в линейный код. Оптимизирующие компиляторы так и делают, выигрывая в скорости. Только вот вижу для x=x`*`x команду УМН Сх, Сх и нет команды для y+=x.

Хотя, подумав еще раз... 
2`*`2 = 4; 4`*`4 = 16; 16`*`16 = 256; 256`*`256 < 1024 STOP ==> 4 раза цикл должен быть исполнен.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, точно. А как дальше? 4 раза с y+=x;?

Comment: Вроде не хватает полной информации по этим мнемокодам. Например, куда записывается результат после команды УМН? Ладно, будем предполагать, что, как в х86, и что есть еще команда сложения СЛОЖ. 

КОП  Ах, #100 ;(копируем из 100-й ячейки в Ах)

КОП  Вх, #101 

КОП  Сх, Ах

УМН  Сх, Ах 

СЛОЖ Bx, Cx

УМН  Сх, Сх

СЛОЖ Bx, Cx

УМН  Сх, Сх

СЛОЖ Bx, Cx

УМН  Сх, Сх

СЛОЖ Bx, Cx

КОП  Ax, Bx ; в x86 результат помещают в Ax

; или, возможно, результат надо вернуть в память на место у - КОП #101, Bx

СТОП  ; здесь предполагаю возврат на то место, откуда был вызов на подпрограмму

Comment: Первые 2 строчки заменил бы на следующие (если это возможно):


КОП Ах, 2 ; х=2
КОП Вх, 0 ; y=0